# Wait for multiple lines to be logged in Ansible

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, aws-cloudformation, aws-auto-scaling

I am running an Ansible script on EC2 with Cloudformation. The ansible script runs when the instance is created and there's an autoscaling group waiting for cfn-signal from the instance.

I want Ansible to wait for few logs to appear. The logs can come in any particular order saying that a module has finished being deployed. After all logs have appeared, I would like to signal the CF stack that the application is healthy.

I have tried the following:

```
- name: Check if applications were deployed properly
  wait_for:
    path: "{{ LOGFILE }}"
    search_regex: "{{ item }} has finished"
    timeout: 120
    delay: 3
  loop:
    - application1
    - application2
    - application3

- name: Send Cloudformation sucess signal
  command: "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal --stack {{ stackname }} --resource AutoScalingGroup --region {{ region }} --success true"
```

However, this is not working and it seems like Ansible is waiting in order. How can I achieve this asynchronously?

Comment: "_I want Ansible to wait for few logs to appear. The logs can come in any particular order_", do you mean log entries in one specific log file? What should happen if the log file is huge, has already all three start entries at the beginning, there was an event in between and you like to start again? You current approach will lead into false positives and incorrect assumptions. Or will such never happen? Are these log files located on several Remote Nodes?

Comment: Are there any other occurrences of `has finished` within the logs? If the log in any case clean and empty, would just counting them a feasible approach? Does the application name is every time the same `application` with a trailing sequence number? Could therefore looking for `app*has finished` and counting them a feasible approach?

Answer (score 1):

Define an inventory where hosts are represented by applications. This can be made dynamically in the playbook, but the static one is simpler and could be useful in future:

```yaml
applications:
  vars:
    ansible_connection: local # for testing
  hosts:
    app1:
      name: application1
      log_file: "path/to/the/log/file.log"
    app2:
      name: application2
      # ... same for other apps
```

Then adjust your playbook a bit. Remove the loop and run the play on `application` group of hosts:

```yaml
- hosts: applications
  tasks:
    - name: Check if applicationa were deployed properly
      wait_for:
        path: "{{ log_file }}"
        search_regex: "{{ name }} has finished"
        timeout: 120
        delay: 3
```

This way you can run it both locally and remotely. Please note that the concerns on false positives expressed by [@U880D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6771046/u880d) in the comments are still valid. Also, if your log files are empty upon the playbook startup, you will likely run into a `ValueError: cannot map an empty file` error, that should be addressed additionally.

Answer (score 0):

For a test file **`cleanandempty.log`**

```bash
START
app4 has finished
line
app2 has finished
another line
app3 has finished
again a line
app1 has finished
END
```

a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    LOGFILE: cleanandempty.log

  tasks:

  - name: Run code which stare at log file
    shell:
      cmd: grep -e 'app2 has finished' -e 'app3 has finished' -e 'app1 has finished' -o {{ LOGFILE }} | wc -l
    register: result
    until: result.stdout | int == 3
    retries: 100
    delay: 1
```

would result into an output of

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************
FAILED - RETRYING: Run code which stare at log file (100 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Run code which stare at log file (99 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Run code which stare at log file (98 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Run code which stare at log file (97 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Run code which stare at log file (96 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Run code which stare at log file (95 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Run code which stare at log file (94 retries left).

TASK [Run code which stare at log file] *******************************
changed: [localhost]
```

as soon as the last application startup has been logged.

In order to **find multiple patterns which are spread randomly over multiple lines** [Matching Control `grep -e`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Matching-Control-1) was used and the amount of occurrences were counted.

Answer (score -1):

you can use parameter async, e.g.

```
    - hosts: localhost
      gather_facts: false
      tasks:
        - name: Check if applications were deployed properly
          shell: "until cat test.txt | grep -q '{{item}} has finished'; do  sleep 3; done"
          register: log_output
          async: 35
          poll: 0
          loop:
            - application1
            - application2
            - application3

        - name: Check sync status
          async_status:
            jid: "{{ async_result_item.ansible_job_id }}"
          loop: "{{ log_output.results }}"
          loop_control:
          loop_var: "async_result_item"
          register: async_poll_results
          until: async_poll_results.finished
          retries: 30
```

Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_async.html

Edit: I've missed the unordered need so I've changed my answer accordingly